# Can one warm cooked food on Shabbat by pouring hot water into it?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul

Is it forbidden to take some water from a hot water kettle and pour some into mashed potatoes for instance? Or any other cooked food?

Comment: Why would you think this is different than making coffee or tea? See discussions at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38180/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48106/.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer** to your 2 questions:

*1. Is it forbidden to take some water from a hot water kettle and pour some into mashed potatoes for instance?*

No.

*2. Or any other cooked food?*

Depends if it's dry, no problem. If it contains [congealed] liquids then there may be a problem if it's cold. (The definition of *Cold* is discussed on this site elsewhere.)

**In detail**:

The Shulchan Aruch in 318:4 [סימן שיח - דין המבשל בשבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0076_L2) says:

> **ד:** **תַּבְשִׁיל שֶׁנִּתְבַּשֵּׁל כָּל צָרְכּוֹ, יֵשׁ בּוֹ מִשּׁוּם** (ח) **בִּשּׁוּל אִם נִצְטַנֵּן**. *הגה: (ט) וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דַּוְקָא אִם מִצְטַמֵּק וְיָפֶה לוֹ;* וְאִם לֹא נִתְבַּשֵּׁל כָּל צָרְכּוֹ, וַאֲפִלּוּ נִתְבַּשֵּׁל כְּמַאֲכַל בֶּן דְּרוֹסַאי, שַׁיָּךְ בּוֹ בִּשּׁוּל אֲפִלּוּ בְּעוֹדוֹ רוֹתֵחַ; **וְהָנֵי מִילֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ בִּשּׁוּל אַחַר בִּשּׁוּל, בְּתַבְשִׁיל שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ מָרָק, אֲבָל דָּבָר שֶׁנִּתְבַּשֵּׁל כְּבָר, וְהוּא יָבֵשׁ, מֻתָּר** (י)  **לִשְׁרוֹתוֹ בְּחַמִּין בְּשַׁבָּת**‏

(In the bolded part:) Fully cooked food has a problem of cooking if it's cold - but only if it contains liquids. However, **a fully cooked food that is dry, one may soak in hot water on Shabbat.**

The Ba'er Heitev adds that **one may even put it in a Kli Rishon** on Shabbat. So (to answer your question) one could definitely pour hot water on it.

> **באר היטב**  (ח) בישול. והוי יודע שכל דינים דאסורים משום בישול אפי' ליתן על הכירה או התנור קודם היסק אסור כמ''ש סוף סי' רנ''ג. מ''א: (ט) וי''א. והב''ח פסק כסברא ראשונה ועיין ס''ח מ''ש: (י) לשרותו. **אפילו בכלי ראשון** כמ''ש סעיף ט''ו דאין בישול אחר בישול. משמע מלשון הש''ע דאם לא נתבשל מע''ש רק נשרה בחמין אסור לשרותו בחמין בשבת וטוב להחמיר אם היד סולדת בחמין. מ''א:

Comment: While I agree with your logic I don't know if mashed potatoes would qualify as a dry food, depends on how much liquids are added to it.