# Using teabags on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, melacha-creative-work

Is it accepted to use teabags on Shabbos?

Obviously, one would have to leave the teabag in the cup (and leave enough liquid to cover it) so as not to transgress *Boirer*. It would also need to be a *keili shelishi* so as not to transgress *Bishul*.

Providing the necessary precautions are followed, is it permitted to use a teabag to make tea?

Comment: If all the precautions are taken then what is left for you to ask about? I don't understand your question. (Note not everyone thinks a Kli Shlishi obviates concerns of Bishul, eg. the Mishna Berura and Arukh HaShulchan. Also note not everyone thinks removing the bag straight to a plate constitutes Boreir.)

Comment: @DoubleAA - I was asking whether apart from the precautions I mentioned, if there are any more considerations, or any Poskim who don't allow it. Is stirring it allowed? As you mentioned, would it still be a problem of Bishul?

Comment: Which Poskim say that it wouldn't be Borer? It is a keli hamyuchad for boirer?

Comment: That's quite broad (and not what you wrote). We've had a bunch of questions about tea here before. If you have specific questions that aren't covered elsewhere go ahead and ask them.

Comment: Which Poskim say it is Borer? The Kevara in 319:8 is also a keli hameyuchad. (I'm not talking about if you let it hang in the air and purposefully drip into the cup.)

Comment: Minchas Yitzchak Chelek 4 Siman 99.2. Although I just saw a suggestion to remove it with a spoon (Shmiras Shabbos Khilchasa, who maintains it is not borer...)

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67559/making-wissotsky-tea-on-shabbos