# Why is making tea/coffee on shabbos not considered bishul

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, cooking-bishul

Bishul/cooking is food prepared by heating in liquid. Why then is making tea/coffee not considered cooking?

Comment: Huh? Why do you think it isn't considered cooking? AFAIK both the Mishna Berura and Arukh haShulchan say it's bishul and forbidden.

Comment: You should quote those who talk about instant coffee and tea bags in order to make the question valid.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20712/source-for-heter-for-making-tea-on-shabbos?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The Daily Halacha [Preparing Instant Coffee, Hot Chocolate and Tea on Shabbat](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=440) explains the reasoning behind the discussion. There are two questions involved.

Instant coffee has already been *cooked* so that pouring hot water on it, is not considered bishul.

Tea leaves, would be *cooked* by putting them into hot water in a kli sheini, so that one may not put a tea bag into a cup and pour hot water on it from a kli rishon or put the tea bag into hot water in a kli sheni. See the details from the citation below.

> **Is it permissible to prepare instant coffee, hot chocolate or tea on Shabbat, by pouring hot water on the powder or tea leaves?**
>
> A Halachic principle establishes that when hot water is poured onto
>   raw food from a “Keli Rishon,” meaning, from the original utensil in
>   which it had been heated, it cooks the first layer of the food.
>   Accordingly, it is forbidden to pour water directly from an urn or hot
>   water kettle onto raw food. Seemingly, then, it should be forbidden to
>   pour hot water directly from an urn or kettle onto instant coffee or
>   hot chocolate powder.
>
> However, there is another Halachic principle which states that one
>   does not violate the Shabbat prohibition of cooking by cooking a food
>   that had already been cooked previously. If a food had already been
>   cooked, cooking it a second time does not constitute “cooking” as
>   defined by Halacha. Therefore, it is permissible to pour hot water
>   directly over instant coffee or chocolate powder. All powders made for
>   instant cooking had already been cooked as part of their processing.
>   Whether it’s hot chocolate powder, milk powder or baby formula, the
>   processing of the powder entails cooking. Likewise, instant coffee has
>   already undergone a process of roasting, and cooking a food that had
>   been roasted does not violate the Shabbat prohibition of cooking.
>   Therefore, it is permissible to pour hot water directly from an urn or
>   kettle onto any instant powder or instant coffee on Shabbat.
>
> This Halacha does not, however, apply to preparing tea from teabags.
>   The leaves inside the bags are raw, and had not been previously
>   cooked. As such, it is forbidden to pour hot water directly from an
>   urn or kettle onto a teabag. One who wishes to prepare tea on Shabbat
>   must first pour the hot water from the urn or kettle into an empty
>   utensil, and then pour the water from that utensil into the teacup.
>   Tea leaves are classified as “Kaleh Habishul” – a food that is easily
>   cooked - and therefore one may not place them in the “Keli Sheni,”
>   meaning, in a utensil into which water had been poured from an urn.
>   Instead, one should pour the water from that utensil into the teacup.
>   He may place the tea leaves into the teacup and pour the water onto the
>   leaves from the “Keli Sheni,” or he can pour the water into the teacup
>   and then place the tea leaves in the water in the teacup.
>
> Summary: It is permissible to prepare instant coffee, hot chocolate
>   and other powders by pouring hot water on the powder directly from the
>   urn or kettle. To prepare tea, one must pour the water from the urn or
>   kettle into a utensil, and then transfer the hot water from that
>   utensil into the teacup.

As hot water is transferred from one utensil into another, it is considered as having lessened the *strength* of the hot water. Pouring from one vessel into another is considered *less* than the first vessel, but *more* than the second vessel. This means that the *cooking* of the tea leaves in the bag is permitted using *irui kli sheni* and therefore permitted by placing the tea leaves directly into a kli shlishi.

[Making Tea on Shabbat](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/735829/rabbi-chaim-jachter/making-tea-on-shabbat/)

> Kalei Habishul
>
> Although the aforementioned Mishna permits placing spices in a Kli
>   Sheni containing hot water, the Mishna that appears on Shabbat 145b
>   indicates that one may not place uncooked salted fish in a Kli Sheni
>   filled with hot water. Similarly, one opinion recorded on Shabbat 42b
>   asserts that salt is unlike spices and cooks even in a Kli Sheni. This
>   opinion believes that since salt is easily cooked (Kalei Habishul), it
>   can be cooked even in a Kli Sheni. The Sefer Yereim (102) believes
>   that since we are not sure which items are similar to salt and can be
>   cooked in a Kli Sheni, we must be concerned that virtually any item
>   may fall into the category of Kalei Habishul. Thus, he urges that
>   virtually no food be placed in a Kli Sheni containing hot water. The
>   Tur (O.C. 318), however, challenges the Yereim's expansion of the
>   concern for Kalei Habishul beyond the cases specifically mentioned by
>   the Mishna and Gemara. Moreover, the concern expressed by the Yereim
>   is not even alluded to by any of the great Rishonim such as the Rif,
>   the Rambam, and the Rosh.
>
> The Rama (318:5) cites the opinions of both the Yereim and the Tur. He
>   notes, however, that common practice is not to place Challah even in a
>   Kli Sheni due to concern that Challah is classified as Kalei Habishul.
>   Parenthetically, we should explain that although the Challah was
>   baked, people were concerned for the opinion of the Yereim that
>   although we believe Ein Bishul Achar Bishul, cooking may occur after
>   baking.
>
> The Mishna Berura (318:42), citing the Magen Avraham, writes that the
>   stringent practice applies to all items in accordance with the view of
>   the Sefer Yereim. Thus, we must be concerned that almost all food
>   items are Kalei Habishul. The Chazon Ish (O.C. 52:19), however,
>   questions the expansion of the concern of Kalei Habishul beyond bread,
>   which is specifically mentioned by the Rama. He suggests that perhaps
>   bread is more easily cooked than other items since it was already
>   baked. The Chazon Ish, nonetheless, honors the common practice to
>   follow the stringent views of the Magen Avraham and Mishna Berura.
>
> Is Tea Classified as Kalei Habishul?
>
> The Yereim's concern applies only to items that the Mishna or Gemara
>   does not specifically mention. The Mishna, however, specifically
>   states that spices cannot be cooked in a Kli Sheni. Accordingly, why
>   do the Mishna Berura and Aruch Hashulchan reject Rav Chaim's ruling
>   that tea is a spice and we are permitted to prepare it in a Kli Sheni?
>   Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (cited in Shmeirat Shabbat Kehilchata 1:
>   note 152) explains that the spices in the Mishna were large and
>   unprocessed. Today, commercially available spices are ground very
>   finely and present a concern for Kalei Habishul. Thus, one might argue
>   that since tea leaves are incomparable to the Mishna's unprocessed
>   spices, they should be classified as Kalei Habishul. Indeed, the Aruch
>   Hashulchan notes that it is observable that tea cooks in a Kli Sheni.
>
> The Kli Shelishi Option - Rav Moshe Feinstein vs. Aruch Hashulchan

Comment: "or he can pour the water into the teacup and then place the tealeaves in the water in the teacup." Please explain something about this. I understand this part to mean from a *kli rishon*. What difference, then, does it make if you pour the water onto the tea bag or you put the tea bag in the water? Can you alos explain why the *kli shieni* is permitted - i.e. what does that do to nullify *bishul*?

Comment: @DanF The teacup is a kli shlishi. Thus, one can pour the water from a Kli Sheni onto the leaves (Irui kli shlishi) or put the leaves into a Kli shlishi that holds hot water. I will add after the quotation.

Comment: Actually, crush beans used for "fresh brewed" coffee are also already cooked, they are roasted prior to crushing.  So, they are not truly raw either.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks. the question would then be are rosted beans considered bishul or would cooking in water be sufficiently different. However, I will make the change.

Comment: It should be noted that the following line is not uncontroversial: "Therefore, it is permissible to pour hot water directly over instant coffee or chocolate powder." Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchatah (1:55) recommends pouring the water into a cup first, and then adding the powder.