# May one combine drink mix powder with water on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food

For example: making iced tea or punch with a powdered mix such as [this one](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Lipton-Unsweetened-Black-Iced-Tea-Mix-30-qt/10307806). This is different than the question of preparing coffee or tea as it does not involve heat.

Comment: Why not? I think that some people use instant coffee on Shabbos. The only question is does the hot water *cook* the powder.

Comment: This site does not provide a psak (and if your question appears to be asking for a ruling, it is subject to closure) but the issues present have been discussed and you can read up on them on sites like https://www.torahmusings.com/2014/08/making-tea-coffee-shabbos/ or on similar questions like https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83502/why-is-making-tea-coffee-on-shabbos-not-considered-bishul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is making tea/coffee on shabbos not considered bishul](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83502/why-is-making-tea-coffee-on-shabbos-not-considered-bishul)

Comment: This is a different question as it does not involve heat, as do tea and coffee.

Comment: What potential issues do you think might arise that you question whether this is permissible?

Comment: Yes - it would be useful if you can present what *melachot* you think may be violated. I'm surmising that one of your concerns may be "coloring" / "dyeing" by adding a color to the water. There is no concern with coloring when it regards food unless your intent is solely for the color alone. You can't add food coloring to food, as I recall.

Comment: If the mixing does not involve heat, doesn't that make it more permissible?