# Hot chocolate on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, maseches-shabbos, contemporary-halacha

If one has a glass of hot water (that was heated before Shabbat) are they allowed to put hot cocoa powder in it on Shabbat? In this case, it’s a solid being absorbed by the liquid, but would it still present an issue of bishul since the cocoa powder is likely transformed in it?

Comment: Edit: possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83506/27180

Answer (score 1):

Although the original psak deals with soup-powder, I think it would be no different with cocoa-powder.

Refer to the answer [here on Dinonline.org:](https://dinonline.org/2023/01/20/is-it-allowed-to-use-soup-powder-to-make-soup-on-shabbos/)

> it would be permitted to put instant soup mix into a kli shelishi. Even if some of the ingredients (i.e. spices, flavorings) in the soup mix were not cooked before Shabbos. Although they may not be put into a kli sheini, they are still not considered “kalei habishul” items that cook easily and are permitted in a kli shelishi. As a side point, it is important to note that there are some instant coffees, nowadays that contain 15% raw coffee beans, to give the coffee a freshly brewed taste. Such coffee may not be made in a kli sheini, but only in a kli shelishi.